# NumbaPro - Smartest way to sort a 2d array and then sum over entries of same key

Tags: arrays, sorting, gpu, numba-pro

In my program I have an array with the size of multiple million entries like this:

```
arr=[(1,0.5), (4,0.2), (321, 0.01), (2, 0.042), (1, 0.01), ...]
```

I could instead make two arrays with the same order (instead of an array with touples) if that helps.

For sorting this array I know I can use radix sort so it has this structure:

```
arr_sorted = [(1,0.5), (1,0.01), (2,0.42), ...]
```

Now I want to sum over all the values from the array that have the key 1. Then all that have the key 2 etc. That should be written into a new array like this:

```
arr_summed = [(1, 0.51), (2,0.42), ...]
```

Obviously this array would be much smaller, although still on the order of 100000 Entrys. Now my question is: What's the best parallel approach to my problem in CUDA? I am using NumbaPro.

**Edit for clarity**

I would have two arrays instead of a list of tuples like this:

```
keys = [1, 2, 5, 2, 6, 4, 4, 65, 3215, 1, .....]
values = [0.1, 0.4, 0.123, 0.01, 0.23, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4 ...]
```

They are initially numpy arrays that get copied to the device.

What I want is to reduce them by key and if possible set missing key values (for example if three doesn't appear in the array) to zero.

So I would want it go become:

```
keys = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ...]
values = [0.11, 0.41, 0, 0.2, ...] # <- Summed by key
```

I know how big the final array will be beforehand.

Comment: Do you have entries for each value? If not, do you want to keep track of which values there are no entries for or do you want to set those to a default value, like 0.0? Also, is it possible for an entry to have a zero or negative value?

Comment: You are talking about arrays in the question, but all the code is showing lists of tuples. Which is it?

Comment: I should have been more precise. I don't have entries for each value and if possible I would like to set those that are not present to zero.

Comment: My notation was not good. I have numpy arrays that get that get copied to the device initially. So I would have two arrays instead of a list of touples. But they would still need to be sorted in the same manner. I found that there is a library called thrust that does exactly what I want but it's not available for numba and the function is called reduce_by_key.  I'll edit the question for more clarity.

Comment: Details matter. Some actual python code and representative data would greatly improve the quality of this question

Answer (score -1):

I don't know Numba, but in simple Python:

```
arr=[(1,0.5), (4,0.2), (321, 0.01), (2, 0.042), (1, 0.01), ...]
res = [0.0] * (indexmax + 1)
for k, v in arr:
   res[k] += v
```

Comment: Not an answer. the question is specific to numbapro and not simple python. unless you are sure it is same in both, this does not hold.